# Problem with Google Sign-in in Android Project - APK - Prod Version Problem

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using google login in an android project. The login process, which works smoothly on devices installed through Android studio, does not work when published on the play store. The app's release and debug sha1 values have been added to firebase and gcp Credentials. In other words, sha1 values created according to debug and release states are available on both platforms. On devices installed as debug, the application can be logged in without any problems, but when it is published on APK or play store, it cannot be logged in. How can I solve this problem?

Below are screenshots for android studio, firebase, gcp. All of these settings are configured for debug and release. However, despite this, I cannot perform the login process in the application distributed from the play store for the prod version.

Android Studio signingReport

[image]

Firebase Conf

[image]

GCP Credentials

[image]

**Updated -> Troubleshooting**

After comment below I added sha1 key in game console to firebase and gcp. This way my problem was fixed.

Comment: Can you confirm if you SHA1 for release is correct. You should get the release SHA1 from Play console where you have uploaded your app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. yes, I added and updated the sha1 key that I got from the play console to firebase and gcp. I think the problem is solved this way. :)

Comment: @PriyanshKedia - Consider posting an answer to make the solution provided in the comment more visible. Also feel free to edit or expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release SHA1 that you have put in Firebase would not match the one for the application you have on the Play Store.

You should replace this with the SHA1 that will be visible in your Play Console where you have uploaded the app. Uploading this SHA1 will help you solve this issue.